# Terminal Window and Vs Code Variables

Tags: powershell, variables, visual-studio-code, editor, filenames

I'm trying to retrieve vs code variable values from terminal window in VS Code, but all of them return an empty string. I need for example, get the name of the file opened in the vscode editor (from a var)

"Ex: ${fileBasename} - the current opened file's basename"

This is the article I found for these vars, but all return empty:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Thank you and regards

Xabier

Comment: For testing purposes you should show the code you are using in the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VSCode-native variables are only resolved in configs and settings files, but they are **not** automatically available in any hosted terminal.

That being said, the integrated terminal that comes with the official [PowerShell language extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/powershell#_install-the-powershell-extension) hooks into VSCode's editor API and exposes it via the `$psEditor` automatic variable:

```
# obtain editor context handle
$editorCtx = $psEditor.GetEditorContext()

# get current open file's path, infer name from path
$fileBasename = Split-Path $editorCtx.CurrentFile.Path -Child

# This now works
"Ex: ${fileBasename} - the current opened file's basename"
```

Beware that the editor context object is a *snapshot* - if you want to know the current file open in the main editor after some time has passed you have to call `GetEditorContext()` again.